# HSM Software Vs HSM Hardware

Tags: encryption

Can I have a software version of an HSM? I have a client that requires me to connect to its HSM, but I don't have any. Can I get software to do this job?

The spec document speaks of MAC key & PIN key.

1. These are acquired from the ERP. The network management request is used to  download which we have to test.
2. Once we have the PIN block, we prepare the transaction request that also contain the MAC Extended field. The request is sent to ERP for approval. This is also to be tested.

Comment: You can create software HSM, please read about security levels of FIPS 140-2, OpenSSL and Mandatory Access Control like stuff e.g. SELinux.

Comment: if you need to connect to an HSM, why do you need one yourself?

Comment: Connecting "to its HSM" doesn't sound like it would require you to have anything like an HSM. ​ ​

Answer (score 11):

Yes technically you can do, or get, the same functions in software but more realistically No because the purpose of the HSM is to do it in Hardware and not Software.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module

Most likely your client is looking to achieve specific security control needs or meet a regulatory requirement. Your best bet is to identify the source of the requirement and then investigate whether other security controls, or your proposed solution, can mitigate the specific risks your client is concerned with.

There are free software HSM solutions (I have never used this and it's not a recommendation per se):

https://openvz.org/Virtual_HSM

Finally if the reason you are asking is because you are hosting your product on a cloud compute platform you may want to look at Amazon's Cloud HSM. Lots of companies have been using this for years.

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is nothing called software HSM, it's SSM (Software Security Module).
HSM stands for Hardware Security Module.

For your question it's yes and no.
If you want to a software application to act as a HSM it will depend on the HSM type.

Normally HSMs are used for two types of integrations.

1. Payment
2. General Purpose

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question and it doesn't add anything to the other answer. You basically answer "yes" and don't say anything more.